# Finding total derivative of a multivariate function in Maple

Tags: maple, calculus

In Maple, I have a function $f(x(t),y(t),t)$ that I want to differentiate with respect to $t$. I know the command for partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, etc in Maple. But I can't find a way to find total derivative $\frac{df}{dt}$.

Comment: So just do it explicitly

Comment: Have you tried the [diff](https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Physics/diff) from the Physics package?

Answer (score 5):

You have this function:

$$
f = f(x,y,t)
$$

so:

$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt
$$

or:

$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
$$

You said that, you are able to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. So, just calculate them and I assume you know the relations of $x = x(t)$, $y = y(t)$ as well. So, everything is ready to find the $\frac{df}{dt}$ here.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a general symbol for this in MAPLE. I need to find total derivatives several times. Doing the manual process is not feasible.

Comment: @ilawid I worked with Maple many years ago, but I believe it should be easy to automate this process. Basically it's a function that you put your symbolical $f$, $x=x(t)$, and $y=y(t)$ into it and it just calculates $\partial_{x} f$, $\partial_{y} f$, $\partial_{t} f$, $\dot{x}$, and $\dot{y}$ and returns $\dot{f}$ based on that formula. I'm not sure why you think you need to do it manually. Note: at the end $\dot{f}$ might not be something really compact or even it's not guaranteed that you would be able to write it down based on only $t$ parameter. It just depends on explicit formula of $f$.